# HTML default text field which is gone by click

Tags: html

I've been searching for the attribute I should use in order to set default text for text field, but this default text should be gone once the user clicks on the text field.
I hope I explained myself well,

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're looking for placeholder?

Comment: No , placeholder is not what I need, beacuse even when you write the background text is not gone.
For example- http://www.sratim.co.il/ - the upper search box - there's text which is gone once is clicked

Comment: that's _exactly_ what placeholder does. Not all browsers (aka IE) support it at the moment, but there are some plugins and libraries, such as modernizer, that add IE support to it.

Answer (score 3):

in html5, there is `placeholder`

otherwise, there are some jQuery libraries that can do this

https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of doing it on old browsers without javascript. A good way of doing it is to use the j[Query watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/).

Comment: the sratim.co.il site uses this plugin i believe